# Weird output regression table from finalfit package

Tags: r, regression

When I try to run a basic regression code using the `finalfit` package, I get the output table but it is split. Meaning that the OR for the categorical variables appear in different rows.

This is the code I used (the one that comes with the vignette):

```
explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", 
  "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = 'mort_5yr'
colon_s %>%
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory)
```

the dataset used is called "colon_s", included in the finalfit package

[image]

Comment: Please add a reproducible dataset to your question.

Comment: @bahi8482 it would be great if you write the image's output instead of uploading the image in your post

Comment: @Nakx that dataset is called colon_s (part of the r package)

Comment: @irajjelodari I tried to write the output but just paste as one paragraph

Comment: Thanks for posting. I can’t recreate this error, though it does happen when the regression output and crosstable don’t match. 
Try the github version of updating via cran. 
`remotes::install_github(‘ewenharrison/finalfit’)`

Comment: @Ewen Thank you so much for the comment. This is still giving the same error. i will try it from another computer later this week (I will also ask help of one of my colleagues as I am relatively new to R).  The main reason I want to use this package is the ability to produce the univariate regression results for multiple variables in a table format. I was wondering if you know of another method/package that can do the same in a convenient way? I tried using for loop  and lapply but I could not get to the output I need. Thanks again

Comment: No I don’t know of another package. Can you provide the output to `summary_factorlist(colon_s, dependent, explanatory, fit_id=TRUE)` and `glmuni(colon_s, dependent, explanatory)`. The `fit_id` column from the first should match the column in the second.

Comment: I was trying the code on rcommander. when I tried on R itself it worked great. thanks for your help and for the nice package

Answer (score 0):

The results appear at the end, they appear in alphabetical order. You can put the factors in alphabetical order and then copy and paste the results to the side. It is not elegant, but functional.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What helped was redefining all factor variables as factorsagain, using something like:

```
colon_s$sex.factor <- as.factor(colon_s$sex.factor)
```

I have no idea *why* this helped, but in my case it did.